# Center img tag vertically next to variable height div, both inside a div?

Tags: html, css

Consider this HTML:

```
<table>
    <tr>
    <td>
        <span class="author">Author Name</span>
        <div class="imgtitlewrapper">
            <img src="img.png" class="image" width="18px" height="19px" />
            <div class="title">Title of variable length, causing parent div to be of variable height</div>
        </div>
    </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

With the following CSS:

```
<style type="text/css">
    .title {padding-left:8px; margin-left:26px;}
    .image {float:left; padding-left:8px;}
</style>
```

The image is properly floating to the left and the title is properly not wrapping around it, but I would like the image to center itself vertically inside of its parent div. How would one go about doing this? The container tags and layout can be changed, but it all has to be inside of a table cell.

Comment: `position:absolute;top:50%;margin-top:-9.5px;`

Comment: What @Shmiddty is suggesting is a great general-purpose solution.  In order to use that, imgtitlewrapper needs to be position relative.  Anyway, There are other options: 1) set line-height of title to the height of your image (19px for exmaple); 2 use display: inline-block for img and for .title and then use vertical-align to align them.  Just depends on your situation.